# Send a mail from outlook by getting To list from SQl server

Tags: outlook

I am stuck with a issue from 5 days.

I need a way to attain following requirement.

1. mailing list is present in Database(SQL server)
2. I have a mail in Outlook
3. now i have to send mail to all the 200,000 mail ids in Database
   **Note one mail can have only 200 mail IDs so
           200,000/200=1000 mails    **Note: this 200,000 count is not fixed it will decrease and increase>
         like jhon@xyz.com will be present today , next day we may need not send to him 
         his name might be completely removed (so DL is not an option)
4. I need a way to automate this
5. All i have a sleep less nights and coffee cups on my desk

I work in ASP.net any PL which meets this need is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you know how to create sql statement for what you need and how to retrieve data from database in .NET. This means that only issue is actually sending this from outlook.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff865634%28v=office.14%29.aspx) is an article that describes this in detail and piece of code copied from there.

```
using System; 
using System.Text; 
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook; 

namespace OutlookAddIn1 
{ 
    class Sample 
    { 
        public static void SendEmailFromAccount(Outlook.Application application, string subject, string body, string to, string smtpAddress) 
        { 

            // Create a new MailItem and set the To, Subject, and Body properties. 
            Outlook.MailItem newMail = (Outlook.MailItem)application.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem); 
            newMail.To = to; 
            newMail.Subject = subject; 
            newMail.Body = body; 

            // Retrieve the account that has the specific SMTP address. 
        Outlook.Account account = GetAccountForEmailAddress(application, smtpAddress); 
            // Use this account to send the e-mail. 
            newMail.SendUsingAccount = account; 
            newMail.Send(); 
        } 


        public static Outlook.Account GetAccountForEmailAddress(Outlook.Application application, string smtpAddress) 
        { 

            // Loop over the Accounts collection of the current Outlook session. 
            Outlook.Accounts accounts = application.Session.Accounts; 
        foreach (Outlook.Account account in accounts) 
            { 
                // When the e-mail address matches, return the account. 
                if (account.SmtpAddress == smtpAddress) 
                { 
                    return account; 
                } 
            } 
            throw new System.Exception(string.Format("No Account with SmtpAddress: {0} exists!", smtpAddress)); 
        } 

   } 
}
```

What I would suggest is to skip using outlook unless that’s really necessary and send email by directly communicating with SMTP server.

Just search for  “how to send email from C#” or something similar and you’ll find a ton of examples.